# Run C executable from Matlab

Tags: c, linux, matlab, executable

I try to run a C implementation of Sift feature descriptor executable from matlab at linux. The script I run and the executable at the some folder and executable is run by the following

```
./sift <tmp.pgm >tmp.key
```

and I trued to run it on Matlab with followings but none of them worked

```
eval('!./sift <tmp.pgm >tmp.key');
system('./sift <tmp.pgm >tmp.key');
unix('./sift <tmp.pgm >tmp.key');
```

I also check the executable from terminal and it works without any flaw. Is there any other way to do that or Do i have any slight mistake?

Comment: What error message or unexpected output are you getting? Try capturing the return status and output, e.g. with `[status,output] = system(...)`.

Comment: no any error, only getting -1 as status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out the problem as the path `/matlab/bin/glnxa64/matlab_helper` has permission problem. After I check the problem, everything started to work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax looks right.

The `-1` status means it's probably failing to find or launch `sift` at all. I know this is basic (and I think someone else mentioned it), but is your Matlab program running from the same directory that `sift` is in when it calls it? The `system()` function evaluates paths with respect to the Matlab session's current directory, not the location of the calling script. If your script has called `cd` for other reasons, that'll affect it. Check your current directory with `pwd` and do an `ls` and `exist('./sift', 'file')` to make sure it's there.

If this is the case, you could make it more robust by calling `sift` with an absolute path, maybe calculated at run time using `fileparts(mfilename('fullpath'))` in the script.

Comment: Yes I am running all at the same path and for sure I do not change the work-space path while program run

Comment: Next most likely issue is probably an environment variable issue, like path or library load path, or possibly a shell config issue, since Matlab can affect those. Check the environment by doing `set > from_shell.txt` from the terminal where `sift` works for you, then `system('set >from_matlab.txt')` from Matlab and `diff` them to see if Matlab is modifying things.

Comment: I guess not any command can be executed at my Matlab. I tried others but no response only an -1 for status.

Comment: That's... odd. It should be able to run basically any program you can from the shell. Maybe a shell config issue? You could check the `MATLAB_SHELL` and `SHELL` environment variables to make sure they're pointing at something sane, and try `!ps`, `[a,b] = system('ps')`, and `[a,b] = system('ps -fEww')` to see what exactly's getting launched when Matlab shells out for you. And, to isolate some variables and get finer control, you could try running the same programs with `java.lang.Runtime.exec` from within Matlab.

Comment: Interesting. (And you'd think it could give you a real error message or warning in that case.) Go ahead and Accept your answer; you've earned the 15 points with your debugging work. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of permission. Just adding solution for others to see as i had hard time finding the solution. 
Open terminal and type
cd \path_of_your_file
sudo chmod -R 777
it will ask for your password and will permit to run the exe. Hugs..